# How to declare DOM as possibly undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

My colleagues and I are currently building a new Vue SSR app using Nuxt inside a monorepo. We have the Nuxt app as a package and another one being our component library. We're all quite new in Typescript, but we were able to set everything up without any issue.

The problem is: the component library should be SSR friendly, but shouldn't be aware of Nuxt itself so I would rather use `if (typeof window !== 'undefined')` than `if (process.browser)` when accessing window properties. Now I'm wondering if I could use Typescript and Eslint to raise an error if someone tries to access a window properties without first checking if it is defined.

```js
// Not SSR friendly
const halfWinHeight = window.innerHeight / 2

// SSR friendly
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const halfWinHeight = window.innerHeight / 2
}
```

I know Typescript will raise an error if I use a union type, something like:

```js
declare const window: {} | undefined
```

then I get the error I would like to have `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

[image: window is possibly undefined]

Obviously, I don't want to declare all possible `window` and `document` properties, so I'm wondering if I could use a [lib](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#lib) like `DOM`, but a DOM that is possibly undefined. The tricky part is the fact that we only know if window is defined or not at runtime so how could I assign it a value to let Typescript know at build time?

I'm trying to solve this with Typescript, but it might not be the best approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

1. Use the `dom` lib to get the type declarations for `window`:

   ```js
   // tsconfig.json
   {
     "compilerOptions": {
       "lib": ["dom"]
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create a utility file that exports `window`, typed as `typeof window | undefined`:

   ```js
   // @/utils/window.ts
   export default window as typeof window | undefined
   ```
3. In all files that use `window` (from `dom`), import the utility file as `window` so that your custom typed version is used instead:

   ```js
   // MyFoo.vue
   import window from '@/utils/window'

   export default {
     mounted() {
       window.console.log('hi')  // ❌ Object is possibly 'undefined'
       ^^^^^^

       window?.console.log('hi') // ✅
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Nice one, but it doesn't really solve the problem of making sure that people don't forget about the fact that `window` can be undefined with SSR. It won't raise an error if I don't import it which is kind of pointless since if I forgot to import it, it most likely means that I also forgot to handle `window` being possibly undefined.